# Using JSON to parse xmlhttp.responseText for populating textboxes

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

How can JSON be used to parse xmlhttp.responseText? I can't seem to get textboxes populated using the parsed data. I tried using .value and .innerHTML with the dot notation with b.first and b.second used with json_encode from the loadTextBox.php file (see below), but the textboxes won't populate.

Main page code:

```
function loadDoc()
{
   var xmlhttp;

   // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
   if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
   {
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
   }
   //code for IE6, IE5
   else
   {
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   }

   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
   {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
      {
         var doc = window.document.createElement("doc");
         var a = xmlhttp.responseText;
         var b = JSON.parse(a);
         document.getElementById("textbox").innerHTML=b.first;
         document.getElementById("textbox2").innerHTML=b.second;
      }
   }

   xmlhttp.open("GET","loadTextBox.php?id=4",true);
   xmlhttp.send();
}
```

loadTextBox.php code:

```
<?php
---Placeholder for correct DB login info---

$result = $mysql->query("SELECT column_one FROM table_one");

while ($row = $result->fetch_object())
{
   $queryResult[] = $row->present_tense;
}
$textboxValue = $queryResult[0];
$textboxValue2 = $queryResult[2];
echo json_encode(array('first'=>$textboxValue,'second'=>$textboxValue2));
?>
```

Comment: Don't do it in the hard way. Do use a third party library such as jQuery :) You'll do it in the wrong way 99% of the time.

Comment: I would highly recommend you use jquery instead of rolling your own ajax thing. what you want is simply an option to the `$.ajax` function

Comment: Do you see any errors in your javascript console?

Comment: I'm using cpanel, so I'm really just using notepad.

Comment: In my question I said I tried .value already, but it doesn't work either.

Comment: try doing `alert(b.first)`, `alert(b.second)` in the function to see what happens.

Comment: @programm3r I mean, javascript console, available in any browser. What browser are you using to test this?

Comment: @ Claudiu I put alert(b.first) and alert(b.second) right after the JSON.parse(a) line, but neither of the alert boxes popped up.

Comment: @programm3r ok, so use ctrl+shift+k to bring up the javascript console and refresh the page and see what errors you get

Comment: @Esailija I did not know about this console. Thanks. The console says on the JSON.parse(a) line syntax error unexpected character.

Comment: @programm3r there is probably some error happening in the server, causing it to send something other than the json, and the `JSON.parse` therefore cannot parse it. You can use `console.log(xmlhttp.responseText)` (inside the onreadystate function, before the error happens as errors halt execution and it won't be logged then) to see what the server sent. It will be logged in the same console the error was shown in.

Comment: @Esailija I see a new line now besides the unexpected character line. The new line says GET followed by the url of my loadTextBox.php page.

Comment: @programm3r You can also manually point your browser to `http://yoursite.com/loadTextBox.php?id=4` (just like visiting any other normal page) and look at the response. Then see, if the response is what you expect.

Comment: @Esailija I'm seeing the same thing I see when using an alert box. Output is as follows: {"first":"radim","second":"radi"}

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have figured out the underlying problem. Extra tags were being sent because I had unnecessary tags in my DB info file. Those tags were being sent in the responseText with {"first":"radim","second":"radi"}. So the code pertaining to ---Placeholder for correct DB login info--- was wrong. I also changed .innerHTML to .value and now it works as intended.

Main page code updated:

```
function loadDoc()
{
   var xmlhttp;

   // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
   if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
   {
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
   }
   // code for IE6, IE5
   else
   {
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   }

   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
   {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
      {
         var a = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
         document.getElementById("textbox").value=a.first;
         document.getElementById("textbox2").value=a.second;
      }
   }

   xmlhttp.open("GET","loadTextBox.php?id=4",true);
   xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Answer (score 8):

This is fully tested and works. Use as a starting point to accomplish what you are trying to do:

```
var url = "YOUR.php"

var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
ajax.open("GET", url, true);
ajax.send(null);
ajax.onreadystatechange = function () {

     if (ajax.readyState == 4 && (ajax.status == 200)) {

        console.log("ready")            
        var Data = JSON.parse(ajax.responseText);
        console.log(Data);
        console.log(Data.first);

    } else {
        console.log("not ready yet")            
    }
}
```

This assumes your JSON output is properly formatted as you stated:

```
{"first":"radim","second":"radi"}
```

Comment: Works for me using your code as well: [http://znibble.com/test.php](http://znibble.com/test.php) for the JSON result, and [http://znibble.com/test.html](http://znibble.com/test.html) for the ajax call. The php source is simply: `<?php echo '{"first":"radim","second":"radi"}';?>` which simulates your JSON output, and you can look at the source code for the html/js from your browser. All works fine.

Comment: I have figured out the underlying problem. Extra tags were being sent because I had extra unnecessary tags in my DB info file. Those tags were being sent in the responseText with {"first":"radim","second":"radi"}. I also changed .innerHTML to .value and now it works as intended.