# Returning multiple values from a PHP function I have called with AJAX

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, function, return-value

I'm trying to return the first row of a table in a MySQL database using a php function called on click (with AJAX).

I have been experimenting with the PHP list function to return the row as an array.

At the moment it isn't doing anything and I'm wondering what I've done wrong.

Here's the PHP function called getfacebook.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<?php

$bname = $_REQUEST["bname"];

$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '12345'); 

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "12345";
$dbname = "success";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
// PHP for execution
$sql = "SELECT id, bname, bicon, rafrica, rasia, roceania, reurope, rsouthamerica, rnorthamerica, traffic, revenue, profit FROM business LIMIT 1";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $b3name = $row["bname"]. "<br>";
        $b3icon = $row["bicon"]. "";
        $b3rafrica = $row["rafrica"]. "<br>";
        $b3rasia = $row["rasia"]. "<br>";
        $b3roceania = $row["roceania"]. "<br>";
        $b3reurope = $row["reurope"]. "<br>";
        $b3rsouthamerica = $row["rsouthamerica"]. "<br>";
        $b3rnorthamerica = $row["rnorthamerica"]. "<br>";
        $b3traffic = $row["traffic"]. "<br>";
        $b3revenue = $row["revenue"]. "<br>";
        $b3profit = $row["profit"]. "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

list($b3name,$b3icon,$b3traffic);

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's the button that executes the AJAX function to call getfacebook.php:

```js
function loadfacebook1()
{
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            document.getElementById("b1").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    } 

    xmlhttp.open("GET","getfacebook.php",true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

And finally, this is what the AJAX is changing on the page:

```html
<center><h3><strong><u>Business 1</u></strong>: <span id="b1"></span></h3></center>
```

The purpose of all this isn't to just change a heading, I'm just using it to test that the returning values are correct.

After it successfully returns the row from the table I want to assign each of them to a PHP variable so that I can manipulate the styling of an SVG (which thankfully I've already got working).

I am totally new to all of this as of yesterday (I'm a designer not a developer, as you have probably guessed by my awful knowledge) so if I'm over complicating things massively please put me out of my misery! I have a feeling I'm making things more difficult than they need to be.

Cheers,

Will

Comment: Why do you use both `mysqli_connect` and `new mysqli()`? They do the same thing

Comment: I think I accidentally forgot to remove one or the other when I decided to change my approach. I'll edit that now but it won't change anything as I don't think the connection to MySQL is the problem. I think the problem is that I can't return multiple variables from one PHP function. Thanks

Comment: You should first open your browser Developer tools and check for JS errors and do you send a request at all. If you send a request check what parameters you send etc.

Comment: I'm not clear what you think the `list()` construct does, but it's not right. `list()` can be used to "decompose" an array, assigning multiple variables at the same time, e.g. `$my_array = [1, 2, 3]; list($foo, $bar, $baz) = $my_array; echo $foo;` Without anything to assign from, it does nothing.

Comment: Your `while` loop is all wrong. You're overwriting the variable with each row, not outputting all the rows.

Comment: You shouldn't put `<head>` and `<body>` tags in the `innerHTML` of something. There can only be one `<head>` and `<body>` tag, and they're already on the original page.

Comment: This question contains a lot of code, and quite a vague problem description. You will get much better help, and may even solve the problem yourself, if you break things down and come up with a minimal test case, as discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @IMSoP I thought that was the problem! In an ideal world I could return three separate variables with three separate values assigned to each of them from the first row in the MySQL table.

Comment: @Barmar Sorry about the random tags - I'm putting this together in a rush and that means I haven't tidied up code I've sourced from elsewhere. I used a responsive template for the page and I think that had the weird sub headings in it. Once I've solved this i'll go back over it and remove them.

As for the while loop, a colleague working with me did it and it seems to be working fine for other things. Is it worth changing it if it is working for everything I need it to thus far? Thanks

Comment: It is working because you limit the query to one row. If you were to remove `LIMIT 1` from the query you would overwrite the variables every iteration.

Comment: @msfoster Ah, I see. Well in this case I only need to access one row at a time. So should I leave it as it is? Or would you recommend changing it anyway? If so, how? Thanks

Comment: Yes, I suggest you remove the loop. Replace the loop with `$row = $result->fetch_assoc();` and then build the `$output` array as @Peter Bowers suggest in his answer. It's no point in creating all those variables when you only need to access them once: `"name" => $row["bname"], ..`

Comment: @msfoster brilliant, thanks. I've got it to return $output array thanks to Peter but now I don't know how to use the array that it's returning. At the moment it's just printing the array with <span id="b1"></span>. How do I take the array and assign the three values in it to variables? Sorry for the massive amount of questions. I accept that I'm terrible at this! I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Parse the response: `var result = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);` and then `document.get...innerHTML = result.name`

Comment: Ah, just realized that you figured it out already :)

Comment: Your comment is still very helpful as the examples are a little out of context. Thanks for your help! Saved me a lot of time and a headache or two. Cheers :)

Comment: @msfoster I've added this to the end of the AJAX

   var result = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
   document.getElementById("test").innerHTML=result.name;

But now when I try to display "test" like this:

<span id="test"></span>

It displays nothing. Is it a silly error or is something going majorly wrong? Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `list()` function is not what you are looking for. You want to use JSON or XML.

To produce JSON output you put all your values in an array and then output it with `json_encode()`:

```
$output = array(
    'name' => $b3name,
    'icon' => $b3icon,
    'traffic' => $b3traffic
);
echo json_encode($output);
```

You may need to make sure you have the headers set appropriately as well.

Comment: Perfect, thank you! I thought I was doing something massively wrong. How would I then display the three variables from the $output array as independent variables in HTML? Thanks again

Comment: Take a look at your xmlhttp.responseText with console.log.

Comment: See examples on this page - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12359047/using-json-to-parse-xmlhttp-responsetext-for-populating-textboxes

Comment: you are a savior. Thank you so much!